# How to monitor the upload process with Dropbox Sync API and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, upload, dropbox, synchronization

My app uploads some file on his app folder with Dropbox Sync API using

```
file.writeContentsOfFile(tempPath, shouldSteal: true, error: &error)
```

I would like to monitor the upload process showing progress in a `UIProgressView`.

I know about the observer block for the DBFile or the KVC pattern but it works nice when the file was downloaded. Instead, when it is uploading, his `status.progress`remains 0.0 for all the time and, just at the end of the process, it becomes 1.0.

Are there other properties that I can observe or other developer pattern that I should follow?

Comment: Checking the DBFile.status.progress using an observer is the right way to monitor the progress of a transfer. What version of the SDK are you using? How big is the file?

Comment: Actually I'm trying with a small file of 1.2Mb and I'm using 3.1.1 SDK. In the observer block I symply have a log of the file status and it logs just one time this: `DBFileStatus(cached=YES, DBFileStateUploading, progress=0.000000, error=(null))`
I also added a method that is scheduled ones a second and that print the same thing, just to be sure that the file still exists and it logs always the same status. The progress never change.

Comment: So you only get one log statement, or two? From your comment here, it sounds like you only get one log statement, but from your question it sounds like you get two. Or, in your question, do you mean you check the status after the upload and see 1.0? If you're only seeing one log statement from the observer during the upload, maybe your DBFile is going out of scope? Also, does this happen with substantially larger files too?

Comment: In my actual project I get only one log statement, sorry. In my question I'm referring to the image grid in sample code. In that example I get just 3 logs, two with 0.0 progress and the last one with 1.0 progress and so I though that the progress doesn't been updated constantly but maybe this is because the file in the sample project is small. In my project I have only one log statement and this is happen even with large files. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The ImageGrid example doesn't use writeContentsOfFile, but in that case it may be that the UI doesn't update fast enough to show all the progress data, and that the logging doesn't print out everything you're looking for. You can try adding NSLog(@"%@", [weakFile status]); to [file addObserver:self block:^{ in Image Grid to get a better view of that. In your actual project, if you do have logging like that, I suspect the issue may be your DBFile going out of scope after writeContentsOfFile finishes, meaning your observer wouldn't fire during the actual transfer (which happens asynchronously).

Comment: What do you intend with "out of scope"? How can I manage that issue?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: You'll need to keep the DBFile open, and not let it be released, in order for the observer to keep firing. You can do this by storing it as a property in your controller, for example. E.g., how filesystem is a property on ImageGridViewController in the Image Grid example.